# Excel Add-in KeyPress/KeyDown Implementation (Visual Basic)

Tags: excel, vba, add-in

I wrote this add-in in visual basic, and I need to toggle it on and off.

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class ThisAddIn

    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup

    End Sub

    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Shutdown() Handles Me.Shutdown

    End Sub

    Sub Application_SheetChange(Sh As Object, Target As Range) Handles Application.SheetChange

        Target.Offset(0, 1).PrintOut(Copies:=1, Preview:=True)

    End Sub
End Class
```

I wrote a pseudo-code algorithm to solve this problem.

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class ThisAddIn

    int toggle = 0 'off

    Sub Press F1 key
        if (toggle == 1) 'if on turn off
            toggle = 0
        else
            toggle = 1 'else turn on

      End Sub


    Sub Application_SheetChange(Sh As Object, Target As Range) Handles Application.SheetChange

        if(toggle == 1)

            Target.Offset(0, 1).PrintOut(Copies:=1, Preview:=True)

    End Sub

End Class
```

I have the if statement and the variable working. I really just need help getting the KeyPress or KeyDown Function implemented.

I would like to use the F1 Key, so I think it needs to be a KeyDown Event.

If you have any suggestions it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To catch keyboard events, you can use [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34875505/1295010) (it is in C#, but not too big for translation)

To skip default F1 action, use this code:

```
Application.OnKey("{F1}", "")
```