# Is it possible to prevent Copy (ctrl + c) in Outlook Read Email using VSTO Addon?

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I am trying to prevent user to copy an encrypted email when it is open to be read.
To restrict right click + Copy I have used contextMenu in CustomUI which is working.
I need to restrict the Keyboard ctrl+c.

Already tried low level hook and it is actually detecting the key strokes. 
[Detecting text changes in Word 2016 from VSTO add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770647/detecting-text-changes-in-word-2016-from-vsto-add-in)
The problem is even if I clear the Clipboard using ClipBoard.SetText(string.Empty) the selected text is getting copied.
I assume the copy operation is happening afterwards.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

I am using C#, VSTO outlook Addin.

Comment: `Windows 10` users could also resort to `Windows+Shift+S` and do a screen copy. Or they could make use of the [Snipping Tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13776/windows-10-use-snipping-tool-to-capture-screenshots). Also, they could print the mail to PDF and copy text from the resulting PDF file.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this. Any idea how to handle this in VSTO for Outlook?

Comment: There is no chance to prevent unauthorized screen copies. Everything a user can see, can be seen and stored by a camera. Such hurdles make life cumbersome but do not reach their goal.

Comment: Thanks, my current input is to restrict copy from keyboard in email body. Interested to know how that can be achieved via VSTO outlook addin

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes to this question, I found below helpful

[Excel VSTO Key hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34874000/excel-vsto-key-hook)